# How to make an external text file a part of the executable?

Tags: c, visual-studio, file

Basically I want to include a help routine in my program, one option I have is to use a lot of `printf` inside a `help` function. I was wondering if I could instead write my instructions in a text file such that it reads it and prints it out, but in that case I would have to pass the file around with the executable. Is there a way to make the file resource a part of the executable itself?

Compiler: MSVC

Comment: What compiler/platform?

Comment: I am using MSVC

Comment: Put it in a resource file that you include in the build? It will however make it very hard to update the help-text independently of the program (as well as when using `printf` calls to output it). Why not use a simple text-file, or similar, to contain the help-text?

Comment: I don't intend to update the help, I guess if I do that I will have to build the solution again. That is fine. So if I include the text file in the resource does MSVC build the text file into the executable? Can you elaborate on what you mean by a simple text-file? .txt?

Comment: There are probably several thousands of examples and tutorials on how to use resource files, how to create plain text sections in them, how they could possible import (*include*) plain text files, and how to include them in your build automatically. And of course how to access the resource at run-time. Please use your favorite search engine for some research.

Comment: I will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the compiler for C-like languages puts static strings in the `.text` section (it may be named differently depending on your target arch/the corresponding assembly specification). You just need to format it properly and assign it to a static string then it will be put into the executable by the compiler.

C++ example:

```
#include <iostream>

static std::string help_text = "Hi, I'm a help text\n"
                                "-a do this\n"
                                "-b do that\n"
                                "...\n"
                                "-a do this\n"
                                "-b do that\n";

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << help_text << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Likewise, define the string in a header file and include that header file into the main to keep the main file clean.

In response to the comment a tiny nasm x86 SystemV example:

```
mov    rdi, vmsg  ; move whats to be printed to the destination index register 
mov    rsi, args_to_printf ; e.g. when using %d or sth. to the source index register
extern printf
call   printf
```

Effectively it makes no difference, it's just a way to move the text to an extra file but still including it into the static part of the executable.

Comment: So is it better to do something like this, or to use printf's to create a help function. What is the difference? Is including static strings faster?

Comment: In the end the compiler (depending on the implementation of course) puts all static strings into the .text section. It doesn't make much of a difference in terms of compilation or runtime; the printfs are called by moving the string into a register specified by the corresponding ABI.